# how to locate the element in <div aria-label>

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, findelement

I am very beginner level in selenium java. I am trying to find the element in amazon.

when I try to run this code, I could not locate the element. please help to fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMWTB.png)

This is my code

```
    WebElement a_review= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='4 Stars & Up']"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", a_review);
            a_review.click();
```

Comment: Strongly suggest you to revisit your question and work on your HTML skills.                                

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570622/selenium-and-xpath-finding-a-div-with-a-class-id-and-verifying-text-inside
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035186/how-to-select-element-using-xpath-syntax-on-selenium-for-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386898/how-to-get-text-from-nested-div-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402132/selenium-unable-to-locate-element-using-xpath-but-firebug-can

Comment: If you can't find your element try checking to see if its under an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply click the element without using javascript. Please try the following code:

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=mega_sv_s23_1_2_1_2?rh=i%3Ashoes%2Cn%3A1983633031&ie=UTF8&lo=shoes");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='4 Stars & Up']")).click();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing. it's working perfectly.